# With python How i can get all specific attribute in ElemenTree

Tags: python, attributes, elementtree

I am trying to get all the `extWorkEquipmentId` and `TYPE` attributes from an XML file. With the attribute `TYPE` I can get it with the function `element.findall`. But I have no idea how to apply this to the `extWorkEquipmentd` attributes.

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<asset:operation xmlns:asset="http://vds.com/assetTypes" timestamp="2015-06-23 08:36:54.129">
  <asset:modelref id="VDS_TIDWORTH">
    <asset:request type="INSERT">
<asset:asset xmlns:asset="http://vds.com/assetTypes" extWorkEquipmentId="7663" extWorkEquipmentType="Esri.wHydrant" assetLabel="Hydrant #PI 4850">
        <asset:relations>
           <asset:relation relationName="ISA95_EquipmentRelationship.ContainedWithin" targetExtWorkEquipmentId="17" targetExtWorkEquipmentType="Esri.wPressureZone"/>
        </asset:relations>
        <asset:measureTypes>
            <asset:measureType name="ENABLED" unit="">
                  <asset:threshold level="0" range="-0.5/0.5"/>
                  <asset:threshold level="1" range="0.5/1.5"/>
                  <asset:threshold level="2" range="1.5/2.5"/>e
            </asset:measureType>
        </asset:measureTypes>
        <asset:attribute name="PRESSUREZONE" type="string">
            <asset:value>E14</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="INSTALLDATE" type="string">
            <asset:value>1986</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="TYPE" type="string">
            <asset:value>Poteau incendie 100</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="DIAMETER" type="string">
            <asset:value>100</asset:value>
            <asset:unit>cm</asset:unit>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="EXTERNALID" type="string">
            <asset:value>PI 4850</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="DYNPRESSURE" type="string">
            <asset:value/>
            <asset:unit>bar</asset:unit>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="STATICPRESSURE" type="string">
            <asset:value/>
            <asset:unit>bar</asset:unit>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="ENABLED" type="string">
            <asset:value>1</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
    </asset:asset>
<asset:asset xmlns:asset="http://vds.com/assetTypes" extWorkEquipmentId="7664" extWorkEquipmentType="Esri.wHydrant" assetLabel="Hydrant #PI 4850">
        <asset:relations>
           <asset:relation relationName="ISA95_EquipmentRelationship.ContainedWithin" targetExtWorkEquipmentId="17" targetExtWorkEquipmentType="Esri.wPressureZone"/>
        </asset:relations>
        <asset:measureTypes>
            <asset:measureType name="ENABLED" unit="">
                  <asset:threshold level="0" range="-0.5/0.5"/>
                  <asset:threshold level="1" range="0.5/1.5"/>
                  <asset:threshold level="2" range="1.5/2.5"/>
            </asset:measureType>
        </asset:measureTypes>
        <asset:attribute name="PRESSUREZONE" type="string">
            <asset:value>E14</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="INSTALLDATE" type="string">
            <asset:value>1986</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="TYPE" type="string">
            <asset:value>Poteau incendie 101</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="DIAMETER" type="string">
            <asset:value>100</asset:value>
            <asset:unit>cm</asset:unit>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="EXTERNALID" type="string">
            <asset:value>PI 4850</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="DYNPRESSURE" type="string">
            <asset:value/>
            <asset:unit>bar</asset:unit>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="STATICPRESSURE" type="string">
            <asset:value/>
            <asset:unit>bar</asset:unit>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="ENABLED" type="string">
            <asset:value>1</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
    </asset:asset>
<asset:asset xmlns:asset="http://vds.com/assetTypes" ex:q!
 extWorkEquipmentType="Esri.wHydrant" assetLabel="Hydrant #PI 4850">
        <asset:relations>
           <asset:relation relationName="ISA95_EquipmentRelationship.ContainedWithin" targetExtWorkEquipmentId="17" targetExtWorkEquipmentType="Esri.wPressureZone"/>
        </asset:relations>
        <asset:measureTypes>
            <asset:measureType name="ENABLED" unit="">
                  <asset:threshold level="0" range="-0.5/0.5"/>
                  <asset:threshold level="1" range="0.5/1.5"/>
                  <asset:threshold level="2" range="1.5/2.5"/>
            </asset:measureType>
        </asset:measureTypes>
        <asset:attribute name="PRESSUREZONE" type="string">
            <asset:value>E14</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="INSTALLDATE" type="string">
            <asset:value>1986</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="TYPE" type="string">
            <asset:value>Poteau incendie 102</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="DIAMETER" type="string">
            <asset:value>100</asset:value>
            <asset:unit>cm</asset:unit>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="EXTERNALID" type="string">
            <asset:value>PI 4850</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="DYNPRESSURE" type="string">
            <asset:value/>
            <asset:unit>bar</asset:unit>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="STATICPRESSURE" type="string">
            <asset:value/>
            <asset:unit>bar</asset:unit>
        </asset:attribute>
        <asset:attribute name="ENABLED" type="string">
            <asset:value>1</asset:value>
        </asset:attribute>
    </asset:asset>
            </asset:request>
  </asset:modelref>
</asset:operation>
```

My python code :

```
        tree = ET.ElementTree(file=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),fich))
        root = tree.getroot()
        print str(root), type(root)

        for child in root:
            print child.tag, " ", child.attrib
            for i in child.attrib:
                print i
```

the output :

```
<Element '{http://vds.com/assetTypes}operation' at 0x7f05c925c150> <type 'Element'>
{http://vds.com/assetTypes}modelref   {'id': 'VDS_TIDWORTH'}
id
```

I try to set the namespaces ,but the dict is empty ...

```
    tree = ET.parse(File)
    namespaces = {'asset': 'http://vds.com/assetTypes'}
    root = tree.getroot()

    try:
        callevent=root.findall('asset:operation', namespaces)
        print callevent
    except:
        print "Oops"
```

Output :

```
[]
```

Comment: Could you add your current python code as well?

Comment: <pre>tree = ET.ElementTree(file=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),fich))
                root = tree.getroot()
                print str(root), type(root)
           
                for child in root:
                    print child.tag, " ", child.attrib
                    for i in child.attrib:
                        print i <code>

Comment: For The moment i try to loop in the element.  
  
`tree = ET.ElementTree(file=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),fich))  
                root = tree.getroot()  
                print str(root), type(root)  
           
                for child in root:  
                    print child.tag, " ", child.attrib  
                    for i in child.attrib:  
                        print i`

Comment: Hello @Mr_Pouet i put my code in the post . I also try some stuff with "namespace" but for now , no result . Thank you for your help

Comment: There are no `TYPE` attributes in the document. However, there are `name` attributes with the value `TYPE`.